# Why SONAR fails at waitForQualityGate() with error 401?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube-scan

Using pipeline code,

```
stage ('SonarQube') {
    withSonarQubeEnv {
        dir ('mydir/') {
            sh "'${mvnHome}/bin/mvn' sonar:sonar -Dsonar.login=something -Dsonar.projectKey=someproj -Dsonar.projectName=somename"
        }
    }
    timeout(time: 15, unit: 'MINUTES') {
        def qg = waitForQualityGate()
        if (qg.status != 'OK') {
            error "Pipeline aborted due to quality gate failure: ${qg.status}"
        }
    }
```

Which progresses crrectly over the first mvn section and breaks on waitforqualitygate() operation:

```
org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpException: Error 401 on http://mysonarserver/sonar/api/ce/task?id=somecode
```

the link is clickable and leads to a filled json structure.

Why the build fails? Webhook seems to be set properly in sonar, and other sonar projects are working correctly, webhook in jenkis also seems to be active.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like described in the [official documentation of the SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins](https://redirect.sonarsource.com/plugins/jenkins.html), you must use `waitForQualityGate()` outside of `withSonarQubeEnv`:

```
node {
  stage('SCM') {
    git 'https://github.com/foo/bar.git'
  }
  stage('SonarQube analysis') {
    withSonarQubeEnv('My SonarQube Server') {
      sh 'mvn clean package sonar:sonar'
    } // SonarQube taskId is automatically attached to the pipeline context
  }
}

// No need to occupy a node
stage("Quality Gate"){
  timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') { // Just in case something goes wrong, pipeline will be killed after a timeout
    def qg = waitForQualityGate() // Reuse taskId previously collected by withSonarQubeEnv
    if (qg.status != 'OK') {
      error "Pipeline aborted due to quality gate failure: ${qg.status}"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I pasted the wrong code. It is outside of withSonarQubeEnv

Comment: I am getting exactly same error when adding Quality Gate step to JenkinsFile.

Comment: SonarQube version is 6.3 and I am using DSL for pipeline. The stage look like this.stage("SonarQube Quality Gate") {
          steps {
            script {
            timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') { // Just in case something goes wrong, pipeline will be killed after a timeout
            def qg = waitForQualityGate() // Reuse taskId previously collected by withSonarQubeEnv
            if (qg.status != 'OK') {
                error "Pipeline aborted due to quality gate failure: ${qg.status}"
                }
               }
              }
            }
          }