# SonarQube waitForQualityGate() returning 401

Tags: sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline

I have a SonarQube server and a Jenkins server. The Jenkins server has the following plugins installed.

- Quality Gates Plugin
- Sonar Quality Gates Plugin
- SonarQubeScanner

I have configured a webhook in the SonarQube UI with the following URL.

http://myjenkins.com:8083/sonarqube-webhook/

I have a Jenkins Pipeline file as below.

```
pipeline {
    /*
    * Run everything on an existing agent configured with a label 'windows'.
    * TODO : Once we have enough agents, distribute to get fastest feedback!
    */
    agent any
    /*
    agent {
        node {
            label 'windows'
        }
    }
    */
    /*
    * We are getting a lot of values from BitBucket notifier plugin.
    */
    parameters {
        string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'PULL_REQUEST_URL')
        string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'PULL_REQUEST_VERSION')
        string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'PULL_REQUEST_AUTHOR_SLUG')
        string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'PULL_REQUEST_TO_SSH_CLONE_URL')
        string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'PULL_REQUEST_FROM_BRANCH')
        string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'PULL_REQUEST_TO_BRANCH')
        string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'PULL_REQUEST_TO_REPO_NAME')
        string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'PULL_REQUEST_ID')
        string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'PULL_REQUEST_TITLE')
        string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'PULL_REQUEST_ACTION')
        string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'PULL_REQUEST_REVIEWERS_SLUG')
        string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'PULL_REQUEST_AUTHOR_EMAIL')
        string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'PULL_REQUEST_AUTHOR_DISPLAY_NAME')
        string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'PULL_REQUEST_USER_EMAIL_ADDRESS')
        string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'PULL_REQUEST_USER_DISPLAY_NAME')
        string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'PULL_REQUEST_STATE')
        string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'PULL_REQUEST_REVIEWERS_EMAIL')
        string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'PULL_REQUEST_REVIEWERS_APPROVED_COUNT')
        string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'PULL_REQUEST_FROM_BRANCH')
        string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'PULL_REQUEST_TO_REPO_PROJECT_KEY')
    }

    /* Add timestamps to the console log. Discard old builds.
    options {
        timestamps()
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '20'))
    }
    */
    /* Stages can be parallel or sequential */
    stages {
        stage('Source-Code-Management') {
            steps {
                git(url: 'ssh://mybitbucketserver.com:7999/dev/sitecore.git', branch: '${PULL_REQUEST_FROM_BRANCH}', credentialsId: 'root')
                powershell "git merge origin/${PULL_REQUEST_TO_BRANCH}"
            }
        }
        stage('Build and Analyze') {
            steps {
                script {
                    // Todo we should be using environment variables or properties for sonar scanner and not have hardcoded values
                    bat "\"${tool 'nuget-4.3.0'}\" restore src/Nemlig.sln -NoCache"
                    withSonarQubeEnv('Local') {
                        bat "\"${tool 'SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe'}\" begin /d:sonar.login=mytoken /k:TEST /n:Website /v: /d:sonar.host.url=${SONAR_URL} /d:sonar.cs.nunit.reportsPaths=${WORKSPACE}\\NUnitResult.xml /d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths=${WORKSPACE}\\OpenCoverResult.xml"
                        bat "\"${tool 'MSBuild-v15'}\" src/Nemlig.sln /p:Configuration=debug"
                        // Note that this shell can retrieve value with CRLF and NUNIT will puke. Must replace with spaces...
                        def dlls = powershell(returnStdout: true, script: '(ls -Recurse src\\*\\bin\\*.Test.dll | % FullName)')
                        dlls = dlls.replaceAll('\r\n', ' ')
                        mycmd = "OpenCover.Console.exe -register:path64 -target:\"nunit3-console.exe\" -returntargetcode -targetargs:\"$dlls --result=NUnitResult.xml\" -output:OpenCoverResult.xml"
                        powershell (returnStatus: true, script: "$mycmd")
                        bat "\"${tool 'SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe'}\" end /d:sonar.login=mytoken"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('SonarQube Quality Gate') {
            steps {
                script {
                    timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') { // Just in case something goes wrong, pipeline will be killed after a timeout
                        def qg = waitForQualityGate() // Reuse taskId previously collected by withSonarQubeEnv
                        if (qg.status != 'OK') {
                            error "Pipeline aborted due to quality gate failure: ${qg.status}"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy Team Environment') {
            parallel {
                stage('Deploy Site') {
                    steps {
                        powershell 'Write-Output "Here we could do a deploy of the site"'
                    }
                }
                stage('Deploy Backend') {
                    steps {
                        powershell 'Write-Output "Here we could do a deploy of the backend and maybe database changes?"'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Smoke') {
            parallel {
                stage('Chrome') {
                    steps {
                        powershell 'Write-Output "Execute Smoke on Chrome"'
                    }
                }
                stage('Firefox') {
                    steps {
                        powershell 'Write-Output "Execute Smoke on Firefox"'
                    }
                }
                stage('Safari') {
                    steps {
                        powershell 'Write-Output "Execute Smoke on Safari"'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('integrate') {
            steps {
                powershell 'Write-Output "Push merge if all is success!"'
            }
        }
        stage('Store Binary') {
            steps {
                powershell 'Write-Output "Put the tested binary in Artifactory. Maybe tag it with SHA and Build Number?"'
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        // Add the publish merge steps...
        // Add the notifiy Jira steps
        always {
            script {
                currentBuild.result = currentBuild.result ?: 'SUCCESS'
                notifyBitbucket()
            }
            nunit testResultsPattern: "NUnitResult.xml"
        }
    }
}
```

I execute the pipeline and the analysis is **correctly processed and uploaded to the SonarQube server**. However the waitForQualityGate always returns a 401.

```
Checking status of SonarQube task 'AWKwODGjKw9CRrvU3S27' on server 'Local'

Error 401 on http://mysonarserver.com:9000/api/ce/task?id=AWKwODGjKw9CRrvU3S27
```

I can see from the logs that the taskID that is generated during the analysis is the same.

```
ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://10.100.1.189:9000/dashboard/index/TEST
INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
INFO: More about the report processing at http://mysonarserver.com:9000/api/ce/task?id=AWKwODGjKw9CRrvU3S27
INFO: Task total time: 3:00.752 s
```

I spun up a local RequestBin server setup a new webhook for that and saw that **it did receive the data from SonarQube.**

```
{
    "serverUrl": "http://localhost:9000", "taskId": "AWKwODGjKw9CRrvU3S27", "status": "SUCCESS", "analysedAt":
    "2018-04-11T07:41:40+0000", "changedAt": "2018-04-11T07:41:40+0000", "project":
    { "key": "TEST", "name": "Website", "url": "http://localhost:9000/dashboard?id=TEST" }, "branch":
    { "name": "master", "type": "LONG", "isMain": true, "url": "http://localhost:9000/dashboard?id=TEST" },
    "qualityGate": {
    "name": "Website", "status": "OK", "conditions": [{
                                                          "metric": "new_reliability_rating", "operator":
                                                          "GREATER_THAN", "value": "3", "status": "OK", "onLeakPeriod":
                                                          true, "errorThreshold": "3"
                                                      }, {
                                                          "metric": "new_duplicated_lines_density", "operator":
                                                          "GREATER_THAN", "status": "NO_VALUE", "onLeakPeriod": true,
                                                          "errorThreshold": "3"
                                                      }, {
                                                          "metric": "new_security_rating", "operator": "GREATER_THAN",
                                                          "value": "4", "status": "OK", "onLeakPeriod": true,
                                                          "errorThreshold": "4"
                                                      }, {
                                                          "metric": "blocker_violations", "operator": "GREATER_THAN",
                                                          "value": "-2", "status": "OK", "onLeakPeriod": true,
                                                          "errorThreshold": "35"
                                                      }, {
                                                          "metric": "new_maintainability_rating", "operator":
                                                          "GREATER_THAN", "value": "1", "status": "OK", "onLeakPeriod":
                                                          true, "errorThreshold": "1"
                                                      }]
}, "properties": {}
}
```

So I have no idea where to go now?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43588403/why-sonar-fails-at-waitforqualitygate-with-error-401

Comment: @abilal17 - I already checked that and could not see a resolution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `waitForQualityGate()` step needs some credentials to fetch quality gate details from the SQ server. The credentials are expected to be set in Jenkins global configuration, for your `'Local'` server.

But according to your pipeline snippet, I see that you are passing manually `/d:sonar.login=mytoken` to the scanner. This is not supported. Please set the token in the global server configuration.

Comment: I have a user called Jenkins in the SonarQube Server. I generated a token for this user. I added this token to the global SonarServer configuration under **Manage Jenkins->Configure system->SonarQube Servers**. I get the **same result**.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you use the right kind and scope for the credential for "Server authentication token". The kind must be "Secret text" and the scope must be "Global".

I had set the scope to "System (Jenkins and nodes only)" and this caused waitForQualityGate to fail with a 401.

Answer (score 0):

OK I got it to work. I updated the Jenkins users token. Copied it and added it as an environment variable in Jenkins Global configuration. Then went through my pipeline script and used the environment variable in all calls to SonarQube.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue like that:

```
Checking status of SonarQube task 'AWo1Ph_4M7P7FGulGL9v' on server 'sonar'
SonarQube task 'AWo1Ph_4M7P7FGulGL9v' status is 'PENDING'
Cancelling nested steps due to timeout
```

I added the following to Sonarqube: **PROJECT NAME** > Adminitration > webhooks

[http://**JENKINS_URL**/sonarqube-webhook/](http://__JENKINS_URL__/sonarqube-webhook/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error (401) on `waitForQualityGate()` when running SonarQube on https but entering it with http in Global Configuration. Changing that to https fixed it.